Specification that tests String value against a list of patterns
I have difficulties defining a specification that tests a String value against a list of patterns.
@Entity
@Table(name = "glossary")
@Schema(description = "Glossary term")
public class Term {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Schema(accessMode = Schema.AccessMode.READ_ONLY, description = "Company ID")
    private long id;

    @Schema(description = "Glossary term")
    private String keyword;
}

Given above class, I have defined a specification that tests against a single pattern, one that tests equality against a list of strings, and another that tests equality against a single string.
public static Specification<Term> hasKeywordLike(String keyword) {
    return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> criteriaBuilder.like(criteriaBuilder.lower(root.get("keyword")), "%" + keyword.toLowerCase() + "%");
}

public static Specification<Term> hasKeywords(List<String> keywords) {
    return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> criteriaBuilder.lower(root.get("keyword")).in(keywords.stream().map(String::toLowerCase).toList());
}

public static Specification<Term> hasKeyword(String keyword) {
    return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> criteriaBuilder.equal(criteriaBuilder.lower(root.get("keyword")), keyword.toLowerCase());
}

I don't know how to create a specification that tests a String value against a list of patterns.

If you downvote, please also add a comment so that I can improve the question.

I have created multiple predicates, one for each keyword, and then combined them via logical or. As identity value for the reduce I used the disjunction predicate which is false by default.
public static Specification<Term> hasKeywordsLike(List<String> keywords) {
    return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> keywords
            .stream()
            .map(keyword -> criteriaBuilder.like(criteriaBuilder.lower(root.get("keyword")), "%" + keyword.toLowerCase() + "%"))
            .reduce(criteriaBuilder.disjunction(), criteriaBuilder::or);
}

